# How to set multiple attributes to the same value?

Tags: jquery

Say I have an anchor:

```
<a id="link" href="" title="">Link</a>
```

And I want to set both the href and title to an url at the same time. So something like this:

```
$('#link').attr('href title', 'http://stackoverflow.com');
```

Is there a way to do something like this?

Comment: `$('#link').attr('title', 'http://stackoverflow.com').attr('href', 'http://stackoverflow.com');` like this ?

Comment: Yeah but I mean setting them both at once to the same value.

Comment: check my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the best answer, created a variable inside the attr() function:

```js
$('#link').attr({'href': (a = 'http://stackoverflow.com'), 'title': a});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="link" href="" title="">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Add in array

```js
$('#link').attr({
    title:"http://stackoverflow.com", 
    href:"http://stackoverflow.com",
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="link" href="" title="">Link</a>
```

Comment: I meant literally the same value, so without specifying the same url twice.

Comment: check [docu](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) it was the best i can see as solution to your problem

Comment: as stated in the docu `To change the alt attribute and add the title attribute at the same time, pass both sets of names and values into the method at once using a plain JavaScript object. Each key-value pair in the object adds or modifies an attribute:`

Comment: Yeah that's why I asked. But check out my own answer, I think it's the best.

Answer (score 1):

You need to chain them together.

```js
$('#link')
  .attr('href','http://stackoverflow.com')
  .attr('title','http://stackoverflow.com');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="link" href="" title="">Link</a>
```

You can use `jquery#each` and iterate through your attribute array and assign your `url` to them.

```js
let url = 'http://stackoverflow.com';

$.each(['href','title'],
  function(index, name) {
    $('#link').attr(name, url);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="link" href="" title="">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [**chain**](http://www.jquery-tutorial.net/introduction/method-chaining/) jQuery methods together, such as in the following:

```js
var target = "http://stackoverflow.com";

$('#link')
  .attr('href', target)
  .attr('title', target);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="link" href="" title="">Link</a>
```

Or **pass an object** to the method, where the two different attributes are the keys:

```js
var target = "http://stackoverflow.com";

$('#link').attr({
    title: target, 
    href: target,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="link" href="" title="">Link</a>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Yeah but I wanted to do it without having to repeat the url.

Comment: @J.Doe -- Just set a variable that equates to the target URL. Then you can use this same variable in both instances. I've updated the answer to showcase that.

Comment: You can actually set a variable inside the attr() function. Check out my answer.